# React Router doesn't "save" url if directly redirected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a React project and trying to implement a proper login page. Therefore I created my `LoginPage.tsx` and another page, that should only be accessible if logged in.
I tried the following code

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={"/other"}/>}/>
    <Route path="/other" element={loggedIn ? <OtherPage/>: <Navigate to={"/login"}/> }/>
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage/>}/>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The redirect to the `LoginPage` works perfectly fine, and by using
`navigate("/other");` inside my `LoginPage` component after login, I'm redirected to `OtherPage`.
However, when using `navigate(-1);` (to go back one page) I always end up on the `LoginPage`.

Looking in the browser history, it seems that it never "saved" "/other" as visited url.
Is this normal? And how would I solve this problem?

It may be relevant to mention, that i use a redux store for `loggedIn`, and dispatch true after login at the `LoginPage`. Note that that's not my actual code, as it is more complex and I'm not actually saving a login boolean in redux, rather than something else, but the principle is the same.

After trying to work on an example (https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouter-login-rq0079?file=/src/App.tsx), it seems like the problem is something else. The codesandbox works just perfectly fine. After trying out a few things, it seems that in my real project, the rerender of my router component (there is also some other stuff that is set there) causes multiple "/login" in the history?
As my first guess, that react router dom doesn't work correctly in STRICT mode, won't work out, as the codesandbox runs also in STRICT mode. However, when running react in production mode, it works fine.
So I'm really confused there.
Is this normal behaviour of react router dom on rerender? Should the router component even rerender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little time trying to replicate my bug on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)
I finally figured out what the problem was, or at least how to fix it.
While working on codesandbox, I realised, that the version number of `react-router-dom` was different (I used `6.8.1`, while codesandbox was using `6.8.2`).

Then I updated my version and it suddenly worked just fine.
Seems like `react-router-dom v6.8.1` has some struggles with the behaviour of `React.StrictMode`, as it added all URLs twice to the history (as mentioned later in my question). Atleast that's what i believe.

Nevertheless, thx @Drew Reese for your help and I hope that others with that problem will find the solution faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are issuing a PUSH navigation action from the login page. This will keep `"/login"` in the history stack. The user will be able to navigate *back* to `"/login"` from `"/other"` after logging in.

You likely want to issue another REPLACE navigation action from the `LoginPage` to the `OtherPage` route. This will replace the `"/login"` entry in the history stack with `"/other"`. If the user issues a back navigation from here they will navigate back to the page ***prior*** to the page they were on when they got redirected to authenticate.

```js
navigate("/other", { replace: true });
```

I see that you also are using a PUSH action to navigate to `"/login"` in the case of unauthenticated users. Here, too, you'll want to redirect instead of navigating to help maintain the history stack.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/other" replace />} />
    <Route
      path="/other"
      element={loggedIn ? <OtherPage />: <Navigate to="/login" replace />}
    />
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: The problem is not, that login is in the history, the problem is that "/other" isn't. "/other" is in my real project a more complex dynamic route, that's why i'd like to use navigate(-1), to go back to exactly that page, i was before loginPage, but the other page doesn't appear in the history (i guess because it's directly redirected to "/login"

Comment: @Sebastian I guess it depends on where exactly a user was navigating around prior to attempting to navigate to `"/other"` (*and getting navigated to `"/login"`*). Using redirects instead of pushes is how you'd maintain the history stack so you don't allow a back navigation to paths you don't want, like `"/login"`. If my answer here is insufficient do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live?

Comment: i updatet my question, it appears to only cause problems in strict mode (double click required), is that normal behaviour of react router, or could it be caused by some rerenders of the browserrouter component?

Comment: @Sebastian If you have issues running the app within the `React.StrictMode` component then I suspect you have an issue with an unintentional side-effect somewhere.

Comment: I can't think of any other way than that the state in my component that contains BrowserRouter causes a rerender that somehow adds another "/login" to the history. Should I normally put my state somewhere else, even though i would need it globally and for conditional rendering in BrowserRouter

Comment: @Sebastian Is the sandbox link in your post an accurate representation of your actual code, what it is doing? I can check it out if it is.